# POSIX Message Queues to pass text between parent and child processes

Tags: c++, operating-system, ipc, child-process

I'm trying to setup demonstrations of different IPCs between parent and child processes. I have the pipe and shared memory implementations down, but for some reason I'm having a really difficult time utilizing a POSIX Message Queue.

There seems to be a lot of errors when I let the two processes loop indefinitely (while the parent sends arbitrary text and the child retrieves and outputs it). Do I need some Synchronization outside of the inherent Message Queue blocking to prevent this? I've seen that POSIX Message Queues allow for signalling. Should I be leveraging this in some way? I guess my problem is that I'm not familiar with their utilization and there aren't many concrete examples of large message passing that I've found.
 Here's my current code:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){ //Welcome Child Process
    char buf[LIM];
    unsigned int prio;
    int errchkc;

    if((mqdp = mq_open(QUENAME, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0666, 0)) == -1){
         perror("mq_open() Child");
         exit(1);
    }

    errchkc = mq_getattr(mqdp, &attrc);
    if(DEBUG){
        cout << "mq_getattr status: " << errchkc <<" Messages in the Queue: " << attrc.mq_curmsgs <<endl;
    }

    while(mq_receive(mqdp, buf, LIM, &prio) != -1){
        printf("RECEIVED: %s \n", buf);

        memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf));
    }

     mq_close(mqdp);
     //}
}else if(pid < 0){
    cout << "ERROR: Process fork() experienced an issue...";
}else{ //Keep going Parent Process
    int errchkp;
    int prio = 1;
    char buf[LIM];

    char* msg = "Friends!";
    strncpy(buf, msg, LIM);

    if((mqdp = mq_open(QUENAME, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666, 0)) == -1){
        perror("mq_open() Parent");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((errchkp = mq_send(mqdp, msg, sizeof(msg), prio)) == -1){
        perror("mq_send()");
        exit(1);
    }

    char* msg2 = "Enemies!";

    if((errchkp = mq_send(mqdp, msg2, sizeof(msg2), prio)) == -1){
        perror("mq_send()");
        exit(1);
    }

    mq_close(mqdp);
}
```

I intend for the Child to receive everything sent by the parent and print it out, but sometimes it exits with no messages in the Queue without printing anything or it simply prints "Friends!" Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Another interesting caveat is that, if I change the name of the Queue and generate a new one, there aren't the same errors.

Comment: I renaming the queue fixes it, I suspect the problem is that you're reusing an old queue that still has some messages in it.

Comment: I thought that too except if I loop the sending and send 100+ messages, it starts to repeat received messages and it never receives all 100+.

Comment: Firstly [mq_recieve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_receive.3.html) message size must be greater than some specified size (read the man page). Secondly, make sure to remove the message queue  `mq_unlink`. See if these solve your problem. You could `ipcs` and `ipcrm` to remove message queues

Comment: This was actually the solution. The storage of previously established pipes and improperly handled messages/message errors were causing the issues. Be sure to properly handle all API calls and wrap them in exception handlers in order to determine that you are in fact using them correctly.